# How to show slope directon and angle

Tags: qgis, symbology, land-survey, geology, landscape

I need to create a map showing slope direction and dip angles in QGIS.

How do I get either:

the dip angle to show up next to the direction arrow

or

the dip arrow symbol to change depending on the slope dip angle

---

I have tried drawing a line with an attribute (dip angle) and then attempting to format the line based on the attribute, which then allowed me to colour code the lines according to how steep the slope dip was. (not ideal to clear data display but it worked) However when I attempted to add more data the whole lot vanished and reloading the layer from an earlier version has none of the dip data on it.

---

Fixed it

[image]

Comment: You need to add more info, like what kind of data you have, what you have tried, screenshots etc.

Comment: I have tried drawing a line with an attribute (dip angle) and then attempting to format the line based on the attribute, which then allowed me to colour code the lines according to how steep the slope dip was. (not ideal to clear data display but it worked)

However when I attempted to add more data the whole lot vanished and reloading the layer from an earlier version has none of the dip data on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have been trying to style your line layer.

Instead, let's create a point layer and set `Vector field marker` symbol styling.

[image]

Comment: thanks  

So this is what I have ended up with so far. Is it possible to change the symbols to make the map easier to read? 
The long arrows make it look like the slope extends far further than it does. 
Example in the top half of the map the slope angle changes from 30 degrees to 10 where the short and long arrows are next to each other. (for some reason I cant get the screen shot to show)

Comment: http://imgur.com/hY1rmIM

Comment: I need to create a map showing slope direction and dip angles in QGIS. How do I get either: get the dip angle to show up next to the direction arrow or the dip arrow symbol to change depending on the slope dip angle (whichever option is possible)

Comment: fixed it http://imgur.com/a/Xyv00   Thank you for your assistance

Comment: @Tina It looks great. Sorry I was offline for a while but now I can update your post accordingly.

Comment: @Tina If this has worked for you the best way to say "thank you" here is to upvote and accept the answer.  See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)